# How to set a method in Spring Boot to execute at specific Date

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an "Ad" Entity in my database which has `activeUntil` field in it.

Now, i would like to create a method on my backend which will execute its logic on Date specified as value inside `activeUntil` property. Basically i want to send User which posted the Ad that it expired. Sadly i have no clue how to do that. Does Spring Boot provide anything like that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use spring boot's built in scheduled task feature. You can use CRON format to specify what dates and times you want your specific function to run at.

The following example is being scheduled to run 15 minutes past each hour but only during the 9-to-5 "business hours" on weekdays.

```
scheduler.schedule(task, new CronTrigger("0 15 9-17 * * MON-FRI"));
```

In your particular case, your scheduled function would pull Ad entities from the DB which have expired and would run the method which you want to execute on each of the expired Ad entities.

See the docs for more information:

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#scheduling

More on CRON syntax:

http://www.nncron.ru/help/EN/working/cron-format.htm

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Spring has @EnableScheduling and @Scheduled for regular tasks. See https://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-boot/enable-scheduling-scheduled-job-example/

Note that, @Scheduled supports cron expression. For the cron expression used by @Scheduled, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html

However, you are asking about regulate tasks based some dynamic Date. This seems impossible for me if restrained by @EnableScheduling and @Scheduled. Instead, try the spring-boot 2.0 Reactive Web. Flux.interval(Duration delay, Duration timer).

Note that, learning the Reactive stack takes about 3 to 7 days. If you don't want to invest the time, just create your own thread that can do exactly whatever you want.